# ggplot2 not displaying values of the Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linegraph

I try to get the values showing of the Y axis but it seems like I can't figure out the issue, here's my code and the results of the plot besides the data:

```
library(ggplot2)

traffic.data <- structure(list(years = 2008:2017, units = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("12,866,461", "13,350,011", "15,106,666", "15,361,841", "15,669,918", "16,498,204", "17,296,885", "17,611,762", "18,239,288", "20,359,883"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("years", "units"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

traffic.data
       years     units
#  1   2008 12,866,461
#  2   2009 13,350,011
#  3   2010 15,361,841
#  4   2011 15,669,918
#  5   2012 15,106,666
#  6   2013 16,498,204
#  7   2014 17,296,885
#  8   2015 17,611,762
#  9   2016 18,239,288
# 10  2017  20,359,883

ggplot(traffic.data, aes(x = years, y = as.numeric(units))) + 
   geom_point() +
   geom_line() +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2008, 2017, 1)) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(10000000,30000000,1)) +
   labs(x = "years", y = "total traffic of passengers", 
        title = "evolution of traffic during the past 10 years")
```

When I ran this code I get the following line chart missing the values of Y axis :
[image: the R plot results]

Comment: It would be great if you can provide the reproducible data.

Comment: what do you mean by reproducible data? p.s: still newbie on R

Comment: Reproducible data means you add the data in a way that one can easily use the same data and try to approach your problem.

Comment: First of all, looking at the distances between your points and looking at your code `y=as.numeric(units)` I'd guess your `units` column is a factor variable and the `as.numeric` is returning values like 1,2,3,... which are not printed/shown in your y axis. You have to find a way to get the number you want, by removing "," separator. Then, the `seq(10000000,30000000,1)` would probably create an ugly y axis labeling. Try a higher value for your sequence step.

Comment: run `dput(traffic.data)` in R and provide the output of that in your question

Comment: Use `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", as.character(units), fixed = TRUE))`.

Comment: Regarding "what do you mean by reproducible data?", please study the [R tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: @Henrik Doesn't work with two `,` (which I find a really unusual format).

Comment: @Dan this is what I get : structure(list(years = 2008:2017, units = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("12,866,461", "13,350,011", 
"15,106,666", "15,361,841", "15,669,918", "16,498,204", "17,296,885", 
"17,611,762", "18,239,288", "20,359,883"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("years", 
"units"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

Comment: Use @Roland 's code to update your `units` column to numeric and then your code should work.

Comment: @AntoniosK I get a blank result

Comment: That's not possible. You'll probably using it in a wrong way. I'll post a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dataset**

```
# example dataset
df = structure(list(years = 2008:2017, 
                    units = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("12,866,461", "13,350,011", "15,106,666", "15,361,841", "15,669,918", "16,498,204", "17,296,885", "17,611,762", "18,239,288", "20,359,883"), class = "factor")), 
              .Names = c("years", "units"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**The problem**

Your `units` column is `factor` and updating it into a number is tricky. Check this:

```
as.numeric(df$units)
# [1]  1  2  4  5  3  6  7  8  9 10
```

Those are the values you plot in y axis. This is why the distance between your points seems to be the same no matter what the actual numbers are and this is why those values are nor shown in y axis, because you specify `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(10000000,30000000,1))` (i.e. to start from 3mil.).

**Solution**

```
# update column
df$units = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", as.character(df$units), fixed = TRUE))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=years, y=units)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2008,2017,1))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(10000000,30000000,1000000)) +
  labs(x = "years", y = "total traffic of passengers", title = "evolution of traffic during the past 10 years")
```

[image]

Note that I've changed the step/distance between your y axis values to 1mil. Having a step = 1 will make the process slow and the plot unreadable.

You can use `options(scipen = 999)` before plotting, in order to avoid scientific notation of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1:**

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(10000000,30000000,1))
```

So, **you are trying to increase from 10M to 30M by 1.**

**Problem 2:**

```
  +   labs(x = "years", y = "total traffic of passengers", 
    +        title = "evolution of traffic during the past 10 years")
```

in this line your second `+` is not needed, and it makes problem.

---

it works well for me by this data

```
dt<-data.frame(years=c(2008:2018),
               units=sample(c(15000000:20000000),11,replace = T))
dt
```

and this code:

```
       ggplot(dt, aes(x=years, y=units))+
   geom_point(data=NULL)+
   geom_line(data=NULL) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(10000000,30000000,1000000)) + 
   labs(x = "years", y = "total traffic of passengers",
        title = "evolution of traffic during the past 10 years")
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I don't want decimal values that's why

Comment: @LazyBrain it is fine, but is the dataset ok for you?

Comment: i suspect that the dataset is what causing problems

Comment: @LazyBrain you are very welcome. it was a competition between me, and AntoniosK